# Updating a game board in steps

Tags: java, event-handling, game-engine

I am building a turn based game with a fair amount of triggered abilities. A single action can trigger multiple auto-casted abilities. I am trying to stay away from a priority system or letting the player choose what triggered ability fires first (like in MTG). This is just unnecessarily adds to game complexity. So I want to try to trigger multiple abilities simultaneously.

[image: gameflow]

In this example ability **A** triggers ability **B** and ability **C**. If **B** and **C** affect different game objects then executing **B** and then executing **C** is fine. However, if they both affect the same game object then the execution order may matter (executing **B** then **C** results in a different state than executing **C** then **B**).

I was wondering how to get around this issue. I was thinking about an event system. Most complex game mechanics boil down to a few simple mechanics (movement, damage, (de)buff, unit placement/removal). I could create an event for each and separate Exeuction into two steps. First would be a planning phase where damage is calculated, movements planned, etc. This data is fed into an event system. After everything is done the events are dispatched and the actions actually execute. The only issue I see with this is if two objects want to move to/be created at the same location.

Comment: I think the reason you're running into problems is the very reason MTG et al force players to order the triggers: conflicts can occur, and there isn't really a natural way to decide which should win. You could, in theory, try to develop some rules about precedence, but passing the buck and getting the player to decide means a) they don't feel bad when your AI guesses wrong, and b) you don't have to invest the time in such an AI, and can spend more time making your game awesome.

Comment: I want to avoid a priority system or making the player choose. Player choice is definitely the easiest implementation. Events are triggered and the player just numbers what order they should proceed in. But so far the execution order has been a fringe case. It seems like a complicated game mechanic to solve an uncommon problem. That is why I want to try to do with it inside the engine.

Comment: Which I completely understand. All I'm saying is that in some (perhaps many) cases it will not be at all obvious what the "correct" order is. Also, this question should probably be closed, since you already know the answer to it: you have to figure out a strategy for handling conflicts that does the logical things most of the time, and the unpleasant thing none of the time.